# Как правильно склонять временно исполняющий обязанности заместителя министра

Tags: грамматика

временно исполняющий обязанности заместителя министра, как правильно написать в дательном падеже????

Answer (score 6):

Временно исполняющему обязанности заместителя министра. Т.е. склоняем главное слово исполняюший-исполняющему. А остальные с ним не согласуются, их изменять не надо.